# how to avoid commands whose length less than 5 being written into ~/.bash_history

Tags: linux, bash, history

I know how to record every command I typed into `~/.bash_history`:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

my question is, after applying above trick, how to avoid command whose length less than 5 being written into `~/.bash_history`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `HISTIGNORE` which takes a colon-separated list of patterns to omit from your history:

```
HISTIGNORE='?:??:???:????' # omit 1/2/3/4-char commands from history
```

Put that in your `~/.bashrc` or similar.